# how to display uwsgi erros with nginx as the reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have nginx as the reverse proxy of uwsgi service, and settings are very simple, just pass the connection to the backend. And when the code has come problem, uwsgi will send a 502 error to nginx, which make nginx only display 502 errors, and in order to check the problem, we have to check the uwsgi log, which is very inconvenient when we are developing. And I search the google which couldn't give me an answer, so is there any method to display code exceptions to nginx instead of just a 502 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use --catch-exceptions but use it only in development, as it could show sensible data